Are $k_\omega$ spaces Hausdorff?
Here I'm considering a particular notion of $k_\omega$-space, a space $X=\bigcup\{K_n:n<\omega\}$ where each subspace $K_n$ is compact and Hausdorff, $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}$, and a set $U$ is open whenever $U\cap K_n$ is open for all $n<\omega$.
Is every such space Hausdorff? Here's a naive attempt, only assuming each $K_n$ is Hausdorff (not necessarily compact):

Let $x,y\in X$, and pick $N<\omega$ with $x,y\in K_N$. For $N\leq n<\omega$, $x,y\in K_n$, so we may pick $U_n,V_n$ open with $x\in U_n$, $y\in V_n$, and $U_n\cap V_n\cap K_n = \emptyset$.
We then let $$U=\bigcup_{N\leq n<\omega}\left(K_n\cap \bigcap_{N\leq m\leq n} U_m\right)$$ and $$V=\bigcup_{N\leq n<\omega}\left(K_n\cap \bigcap_{N\leq m\leq n} V_m\right).$$
Suppose we had $z\in U\cap V$. Then we'd have $$z\in K_{n_1}\cap \bigcap_{N\leq m\leq n_1}U_m$$ and $$z\in K_{n_2}\cap \bigcap_{N\leq m\leq n_2}V_m$$ for some $N\leq n_1<\omega$ and $N\leq n_2<\omega$. Let $n=\min(n_1,n_2)$. It follows that $z\in K_n$, $z\in U_n$, and $z\in V_n$. This contradicts $U_n\cap V_n\cap K_n=\emptyset$, so we have $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

Must $U,V$ be open though?

I'll show a more general result, using basically the same ideas as the other answer.

Theorem: Every $k_\omega$-space is $T_4$ (i.e., normal Hausdorff).

So let $\{K_n:n<\omega\}$ be an increasing sequence of compact Hausdorff sets in $X$ that witnesses the $k_\omega$ property.
Lemma: Given an increasing sequence of sets $W_n\subseteq K_n$ with $W_n$ open in $K_n$, the union $W=\bigcup_n W_n$ is open in $X$.
Proof: By the $k_\omega$ property, it is enough to show that $W\cap K_m$ is open in $K_m$ for every m.  Because the sequence of $W_n$ is increasing, $W\cap K_m$ is the union of the $W_n\cap K_m$ for $n\ge m$.  But for such $n$, $W_n\cap K_m=(W_n\cap K_n)\cap K_m$ is open in $K_m$ since $W_n\cap K_n$ is open in $K_n$.  And therefore $W\cap K_m$ is also open in $K_m$ as a union of open sets.
Proof of Theorem:
Let us first show $X$ is $T_1$.  Given a point $x\in X$, the intersection $\{x\}\cap K_n$ is either $\emptyset$ or $\{x\}$, which is closed in $K_n$ because $K_n$ is Hausdorff.  So the singleton $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$ by the $k_\omega$ property.
To show $X$ is normal, I'll reproduce the argument on page 113 of the paper A survey of $k_\omega$-spaces by Franklin & Smith Thomas.
First note that each $K_n$ is closed in $X$ (easy to check using the $k_\omega$ property).
Suppose $E$ and $F$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$. By normality of the compact Hausdorff subspace $K_1$, the sets $E\cap K_1$ and $F\cap K_1$ have $K_1$-open neighborhoods $U_1$ and $V_1$ whose closures are disjoint. Let $E_1=E\cup\overline{U_1}$ and $F_1=F\cup\overline{V_1}$, which are disjoint closed sets in $X$.  Then $E_1\cap K_2$ and $F_1\cap K_2$ have $K_2$-open neighborhoods $U_2$ and $V_2$ whose closures are disjoint.  Continuing in this way, one produces increasing sequences of sets $U_n$ and $V_n$ open in $K_n$ with $E\subseteq\bigcup_n U_n$ and $F\subseteq\bigcup_n V_n$, and with $\bigcup_n U_n$ and $\bigcup_n V_n$ disjoint.  These unions are open in $X$ by the Lemma, and thus are disjoint open neighborhoods of $E$ and $F$.

The answer is shown to be "yes" via Lemma 1.4.b here, exploiting normality (via compactness) of each $X_n$ (that is, not the attempt I suggested earlier).

Take $x,y$ distinct in $X$, and choose $N<\omega$ such that $x,y\in K_N$. By the $T_4$ property of $K_N$, $U_N,V_N\subseteq K_N$ be open (in $K_N$) neighborhoods of $x,y$ such that $cl_{K_N}(U_N)\cap cl_{K_N}(V_N)=\emptyset$.
Suppose $U_n,V_n\subseteq K_n$ have been chosen for $N\leq n<\omega$ such that $cl_{K_n}(U_n)\cap cl_{K_n}(V_n)=\emptyset$. Note $K_n$ is a compact subset of $K_{n+1}$, and is thus closed in $K_{n+1}$. Thus $cl_{K_n}(U_n)=cl_{K_{n+1}}(U_n)$ and $cl_{K_n}(V_n)=cl_{K_{n+1}}(V_n)$. Since $cl_{K_{n+1}}(U_n)\cap cl_{K_n}(V_{n+1})=\emptyset$, we may choose $U_{n+1}\supseteq cl_{K_{n+1}}(U_n)$ and $V_{n+1}\supseteq cl_{K_{n+1}}(U_n)$ open (in $K_{n+1}$) such that $cl_{K_{n+1}}(U_{n+1})\cap cl_{K_{n+1}}(V_{n+1})=\emptyset$.
Let $U=\bigcup\{U_n:N\leq n<\omega\},V=\bigcup\{V_n:N\leq n<\omega\}$, which are disjoint by construction. We claim they are open, by showing that if $\{K_n:n<\omega\}$ witnesses $k_\omega$, then any union $W=\bigcup\limits_{N\leq n<\omega}W_n$ of sets $W_n\subseteq K_n$ open in $K_n$ and with $W_n\subseteq W_{n+1}$ is open in $X$.
Consider $z\in W\cap K_m$ for $m<\omega$, so $z\in W_n\cap K_m$ for some $N\leq n<\omega$. If $m\leq n$, note $W_n\subseteq W$ is an open neighborhood of $z$ in $K_n$, so $W_n\cap K_m\subseteq W\cap K_m$ is an open neighborhood of $z$ in $K_m\subseteq K_n$. If $m\geq n$, note $z\in W_m\subseteq W\cap K_m$ is an open neighborhood of $z$ in $K_m$. Thus $W\cap K_m$ is open in $K_m$, making $W$ open in $X$ by the $k_\omega$-space property.

It'd be interesting to see an example where $T_2$ does not hold for $X$ when each $K_n$ is only guaranteed to be $T_2$.

I don't think the union of the $W_n$ is open in general.  But it can be made to work, and is even easier, if the $W_n$ form an increasing sequence.

Good catch. I had used the assumption $W_n\subseteq W_m$ for $n\leq m$ when I claimed $z\in W_n\cap K_m \Rightarrow z\in W_m$ in the case $m\geq n$. I'll add that clarification. (And thanks for improving the result in your own answer!)
